# How to find a law firm that is verified by Quebec government?

Tags: immigration, canada

I heard that there are only a few law firms that are verified by Quebec's government that can provide immigration support.

Though there are many search results from Google, I still like to find the verified one.

Does anyone know how to find such information?

Comment: While governments regulate who can practice law and who cannot, governments do not usually regulate _what type of law_ a lawyer can practice, nor do governments rate or evaluate those who are allowed to practice.. Where have you read or heard about the Quebec government "verifying" a law firm? Are you perhaps thinking of the [Quebec Immigration Lawyers' Association](https://www.aqaadi.com/en/home)? This is a professional association of Quebec lawyers who practice immigration law, but the association is not part of the Quebec government.

Comment: I talked to a local agent in my country. They told me they will provide legal service to us by working with a “verified law firm in Quebec” but refused to tell me more context.

Comment: If someone told me the Quebec government "verified" lawyers, I would believe that someone wanted to get my money to "connect" me to one of those "verified" firms. I'm sorry, but this scenario positively reeks of dishonesty and fraud. You should not engage in any way with a "local agent," who will charge you as much money as he can, and will then deliver nothing...except demands for more money from you. If you want an actual, competent immigration lawyer in Quebec, contact directly the Quebec Immigration Lawyers' Association.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply and information! I will try to google and find law firms in Quebec directly. So is there any reliable method to confirm whether a law firm from Google is a genuine law firm rather than an agency?

Comment: Yes. In my earlier comment, I wrote: "If you want an actual, competent immigration lawyer in Quebec, contact directly the Quebec Immigration Lawyers' Association." Do that. Follow the "Find a Lawyer" link that appears towards the top of the Association's home page. You can deal with a lawyer and/or a law firm directly; you  do not need the intercession of an "agent."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I heard that there are only a few law firms that are verified by Quebec's government that can provide immigration support.

All lawyers members of the *Barreau du Québec* and notaries (see note) of the *Chambre des notaires du Québec* are authorized to represent clients with the Quebec government on immigration matters. This is as far as government verification goes for lawyers and notaries. The membership in the professional associations (Barreau or Chambre) is the *minimum* requirement for someone to practice law in Quebec.

Of course, lawyers have their fields of specializations (in contracts, personal injury, immigration, criminal defence etc.). But the government does not directly regulate this;  in some cases  practicing outside one's knowledge may be an ethical violation which can be sanctioned by the law society.

Different rules apply to regulated immigration consultants who are members of the College of Immigration and Citizenship Consultants. They are not lawyers but are authorized to provide immigration-related advice and represent clients with the Government of Canada (i.e. the federal government) and in some cases before the Immigration and Refugee Board (but not the courts).

Under federal law, only lawyers, Quebec notaries, Ontario paralegals (if their scope of practice includes immigration), and regulated immigration consultants can provide advice or represent clients, for consideration (e.g. a fee), in relation to immigration matters in Canada.

---

## Recognition of immigration consultants in Quebec

Immigration is also a shared power under the Canadian constitution and provinces also have a role within their sphere. This is particularly true to Quebec who selects its own immigrants and does not participate in federal programs.

Quebec imposes additional requirements on regulated immigration consultants. For them to represent clients with the Government of Quebec or provide advice related to Quebec immigration law, they must fulfill certain requirements (knowledge of French, passing a test on Quebec immigration law etc.) and be recognized by the Quebec Minister of Immigration, Francization and Integration (MIFI).

---

## To verify if one is authorized to provide immigration advice on Quebec's immigration programs

1. The *Barreau du Québec* provides a [directory service](https://www.barreau.qc.ca/fr/bottin-des-avocats/#!/search) to find lawyers by area of law. You can [verify if a claimed Quebec lawyer is a member in good standing in Quebec](https://www.barreau.qc.ca/en/doing-business-with-lawyer/verifying-status-lawyer/).
2. For notaries, there is a [directory service](https://trouverunnotaire.cnq.org/en/find-a-notary.html) by area of practice (incl. immigration and citizenship] provided by the *Chambre des notaires du Québec*. A verification service is also available on the same page.
3. For regulated consultants, the list is available at [the page from MIFI](http://www.mifi.gouv.qc.ca/fr/reglementation-consultants/index.html) (which also includes a list of persons whose licence is revoked!) and the [government data register](https://www.donneesquebec.ca/recherche/dataset/registre-quebecois-des-consultants-en-immigration/resource/3351c4c7-bea5-433b-82a9-57e00489beaf).
4. The College of Immigration and Citizenship Consultants also provides a [public register of its members](https://college-ic.ca/protecting-the-public/find-an-immigration-consultant). Note that unless a regulated consultant is recognized by MIFI, they are not authorized to provide advice or assistance on Quebec immigration law or represent clients before the Quebec government.

---

Note: Other than for criminal and public law, Quebec follows the civil law (or continental law) tradition. Notaries are fully trained legal professionals (with the same undergraduate degrees as lawyers with specific postgraduate training as notaries) who can offer legal advice in all domains of law in Quebec. It is in a limited way comparable to solicitors in some jurisdictions since notaries generally do not represent clients before a court in a controversial litigation.  It is not comparable to notaries publics in most common law jurisdictions (incl. all other provinces in Canada). Notaries in other provinces are NOT allowed to provide advice on immigration matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed information!